# Is there a way to recover a word document password?

Tags: password, recovery

I have several password protected word docs that I have forgotten the password for. Is there a way to recover them? I am using Word 2011.

Comment: would would be the purpose of a password if it can be recovered?

Comment: While I agree with Buscar, you should google `recover word document password` and/or `recover word document password mac`.  There is more than one way to break that password.

Answer (score 2):

There is good software for this (not free though): http://elcomsoft.com/aopr.html
You can also google for some online services in addition to what Tyson said.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to Ranklord's answer, [iSeePassword](http://www.iseepassword.com/office-password-recovery.html) claims to be able to unlock these files and/or recover the password.
Beware that it is a commercial product, but it does have a "Free Trial".